# Adding the password reset to Django Admin goes to a wrong URL?

Tags: django

I'm following the section on [Adding a password reset feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature) to the Django Admin, which asks you to add these four paths:

```
path('admin/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset'),
path('admin/password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

When I add them, the "Forgotten your password or username?" link appears on the Django Admin log in screen, and if I click it, it works, it even sends the email, but after the email, I end up with this error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/password_reset/done/
Raised by:  django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetDoneView
```

404... well... yes... that's not where `password_reset/done` is. And the link in the email is for: `http://localhost:8000/accounts/reset/Mjk/5...9`, so, against, that's not where `reset/<uidb64>/<token>/`. Why are these URLs in the wrong place, `/accounts/` instead of `/admin/`.

My full URL patterns look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset'),
    path('admin/password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("", views.index, name="homepage")
]
```

I'm guessing then that those redirects go to `/accounts/` because of this `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`, is that correct? is there another way of controlling them? I'm mostly trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: You've have included the views twice. Once individually, and once in [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L17). If you don't want to use the defaults in `django.contrib.auth.urls`, then remove that `include()`, and add any other URL patterns that you need manually (e.g. login/logout). You haven't shown the full traceback, so I can't tell why the `PasswordResetDoneView` is throwing the 404.

Comment: Why you don't use a overwrite admin model for your reset password ? 
Create a folder templates - in this folder registration - and copie password_reset_form.html (you can find this on github [password_reset_form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html))
And you can use this easy with a same call in admin panel

Comment: Have duplicate url patterns using the same views shouldn't be a problem, but duplicating pattern names is a problem. You should namespace your regular auth urls (the `accounts/` patterns) so they all start with "account:", e.g. "account:password_reset_done". I'm on Django 1.11 and see that the auth urls aren't namespaced by default, that's probably still the case on Django 2.1

Answer (score 1):

To send a password reset email containing another URL, I believe you need to add a separate email template. And to do that, you'll need to create a different view that links to that template. You can use Django's auth views by subclassing them and only define the settings you need to be different.

Here's how to create a custom password reset view generally, which can be used alongside the default one:

```
# urls.py

from .views import CustomPasswordResetView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # URL to submit your email address for reset link
    path('admin/password-reset', CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='custom_password_reset'),
    # URL link in email, lands on password reset form
    path('admin/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='custom_password_reset_confirm'),
    ...
]

# views.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView

class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/custom_password_reset_email.html'
```

By default, Django uses the password reset email template in `django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html`. The default HTML templates relating to password resets are there too.

To specify your own template, create another `registration` directory somewhere in your project templates (e.g. `users/templates/registration/` and create the file there. Make sure to give it a different name from Django's default templates, e.g. `registration/custom_password_reset_email.html`, then copy and paste the default email text into it, and change the named URL to the one you want, i.e. `{% 'custom_password_reset_confirm' %}`.

You can subclass the other relevant views (`PasswordChange`, `PasswordChangeDone` etc.) to override other default settings as needed, such as HTML template, form class and redirect URL. All the password reset views are in [`django.contrib.auth.views`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py). The auth views are provided as class-based views (alongside the older standard function-based views, which were removed as of Django version 2.1).