# Using an alternative model for password reset in Django

Tags: django

Due to the complexities of the application I'm creating, I ended up with three user models. One which is pretty much the normal `User` which is not used for anything other than admin and two others. I wrote my own set of auth backends to deal with it and it's working well.

Now my problem is having a reset password system. Is there a way to use Django's reset password views while using a custom model?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866832/adding-the-password-reset-to-django-admin-goes-to-a-wrong-url) about password resets which touches on a lot of similar ground.

I haven't tried password resets with multiple user models myself, but if you look at Django's auth views in [django.contrib.auth.views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py), in `PasswordResetConfirmView` - the view that handles the reset form - it has a `get_user()` method which fetches the user model. And the `form_valid()` method performs user authentication. So if you subclass this view as per my other answer and write your own versions of these methods to handle your non-default user model, that should be the way to go.

I don't know about your specific case, but if you were starting again, the best way would probably be to set the default user (as specified in `AUTHOR_USER_MODEL`) to an extension of Django's `AbstractUser`, and from there you can customise your user model with different user types and roles. Apologies if you already did that, and of course changing user models on an existing app is difficult and risky. But I think with that design, one password reset link would cover all users. Here's a good [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) laying out that approach.